# Unable to locate element because of a dynamic xpath

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So here is the current XPath i'm trying to use.

```
//*[@id="highcharts-33"]/svg/g[3]/g[1]/text
```

The problem is that this is a Dynamic Xpath, so it goes like "highcharts-33", "highcharts-34" etc... I'm making screenshots of theses graphs by clicking on a checkbox. Each time the checkbox is checked/unchecked the next graphs will have a different ID.

Here is the error i'm getting in the cmd :

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]/svg/g[3]/g[1]/text"}

You can see here i'm trying to use "contains". I also tried to use "starts-with" but i'm still unable to locate the graph.

Here are the things i've tried :

```
textvote = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'highcharts-')]/svg/g[3]/g[1]/text").text
textvote = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts-')]/svg/g[3]/g[1]/text").text
```

I searched on stack overflow and saw some topics on it and it was always starts-with/contains or an unanswered topic. So i may be using starts-with/contains wrong.

If you want me to share more code, don't hesitate.
Thank you.

Edit : Adding relevent HTML

```
<div id="chartListContainer">
<div id="chart0" class="gauge-chart" data-highcharts-chart="16"><div      class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-33"
<div class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-33"
<svg version="1.1"
<g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-tracker"
<g zIndex="1"
<text x="0" zIndex="1" style="font-size:30px;font-family:Open Sans;color:#1abb1a;fill:#1abb1a;" y="32"><tspan>80.0% (4 votes)</tspan></text>
```

I'm trying to extract the text from that last line.

Comment: add the relevent html also with one or two levels above

Comment: Need to share your HTML as well..

Comment: Please paste the html of the element.

Comment: Sorry, added what was useful. Tell me if you need more.

Comment: It should be good now, that's the minimal code i can give you to get to that last line. I don't think i need to go higher than that.

Comment: @xZeasy in the html u have two divs with the same id and class in the second and third line. Can you check?

Comment: Try as `self.driver.find_element_by_css("*[zIndex='1']").text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that there's only one `<text>` element inside your `<div id="highcharts-*>` element so you could try CSS selector `div[id^="highcharts"] text`

```
textvote = self.driver.find_element_by_css("div[id^='highcharts-'] text").text
```

This CSS selects all `<text>` elements inside a `<div>` element with id starting with "highcharts-", but if you have more than one `<text>` elements you might run into troubles.

EDIT:

After another look seems that I was wrong to assume that there was only one `<text>` element there, a fixed CSS selector to mimic your xpath one is:

```
textvote = self.driver.find_element_by_css("div[id^='highcharts-']>svg>g:nth-of-type(3)>g:nth-of-type(1)>text").text
```

Comment: There was indeed more than one <text> element so your second idea worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.